# Force pytest to always run a specific test, regardless of "-k"

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to add a test to my pytest suite that will verify the python version that is used to run the test and fail and stop testing if the version is lower than 3.8.
I'd like to get pytest to always run this test, regardless of any "-k" filtering done on the command line.

For reference, this is the actual test (any comment on improving it will also be appreciated):

```py
@pytest.mark.tryfirst
def test_python_version():
    version = sys.version_info
    if version.major < 3:
        logging.error("python2 is not supported")
        pytest.exit("Stopped testing")
    elif version.minor < 8:
        logging.warning("Use python 3.8 or higher for best results")
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should instead use a [hook](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#hooks) or a fixture with [autouse](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#autouse-fixtures-xunit-setup-on-steroids).

Comment: A fixture will not show up as a test in the console. It seems like a pretty reasonable thing to have in a testing framework, to specify that a specific test must pass and if not that the testing session should terminate... I'll look into hooks, but it appears to me that what I need is to define a new pytest decorator, something like "@pytest.mark.mustpass" or something. I don't really know how to do this :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably late, I was able to achieve the same using the pytest_configure hook and the pytest_collection_modifyitems hook. Hope it helps someone.

```
def pytest_configure(config):
    keyword = config.option.keyword
    file_or_dir = config.option.file_or_dir
    markers = config.option.markexpr

    if len(file_or_dir) > 0:
        config.option.file_or_dir.append('unittesting/test_authentication.py::test_authenticate')

    if keyword != '':
        config.option.keyword = 'test_authenticate or '+ keyword
    
    if markers != '':
        config.option.markexpr = 'authenticate_must or '+ markers


def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    auth_tests = [list(filter(lambda x:x.name == 'test_authenticate', items))[0]]
    logout_tests = list(filter(lambda x:x.name == 'test_logout', items))
    other_tests = list(filter(lambda x:x.name not in ('test_authenticate','test_logout'), items))
    items[:] = auth_tests + other_tests + logout_tests
```